# add two shadows with different colors on UIView?

Tags: swift, uiview, shadow, uibezierpath

I am going to make 3D effect to uiview and add shadows like in the following image. there is white shadow on top and left sides and gray shadow on right and bottom side.

I already added white shadow on top and left sides.

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYTcG.png)

```
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -4.0, height: -4.0)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Is it possible to achieve the following result by uibezierPath?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfb9Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a creating another layer with the other shadow color and change the offset. Then add this sublayer underneath

```
layer.addsubview(yourNewView)
```